# Adb shell command can i use to open language settings directly?

Tags: android, adb

I have found that in order to change the language on a device using an adb shell command requires the device to be rooted. Since this is something I don't want to do, I am looking for an adb shell command that opens up the language settings of a device, comparable to:

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings

Comparable, is there any database that I can use to find out more about these adb commands?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For newer devices (3.0 and above) that use fragments, use:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings -e :android:show_fragment com.android.settings.LocalePicker
```

For older devices (2.3 and below) that don't use fragments, use:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.LocalePicker
```

Also, for a reference you can just type `adb` into your terminal and it will display a list of commands that ADB supports. For the am command specifically, you can type `adb shell am` and it will display a list of options. In most cases if you do not specify any options for an ADB command, it will display help information for that command.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer appears to be out-of-date. On a phone running Android 10, I'm able to launch the locale settings screen via the `Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS` Intent action, which is `android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS`:

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS
```

For other Settings Intent actions, see source code for the `android.provider.Settings` class, currently available here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.